# How to update a bar button item in a toolbar

Tags: xcode, uinavigationbar, uitoolbar, playback, ios

I have a single playback controller in my app on the navigation bar and is easily found in its implementation file.  So I've tried to add a toolbar and move the playback controls to that toolbar, but I don't know how to reference it programmatically and therefore cannot update the image used to indicate if music can be paused or played.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a couple of ways, one is by setting the image of the UIBarButtonItem not to be confused  with the backgroundImage of a button.  You can add a bar button like so:

UIBarButtonItem *barButton1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"camera.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action: @selector(pressButton1:)];

The image should be a grayscale image somewhere around 30 x 30 in size much like a tab bar icon.  Declare the bar button in the interface file and you can set the image like this:

[barButton1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Chats.png"]];

The other way you can do this is by using a custom UIButton like so:

button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 64, 30);
[button1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"camera.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[button1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Chats.png"] forState: UIControlStateSelected];
[button1 setTitle:@"Camera" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button1.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(pressButton1:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *barButton1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button1];

Declare button1 in the interface file and then you can change the image like so:

[button1 setSelected:TRUE];

Comment: Seriously, stop spamming links to your stuff in your answers.